# How do you greedily extract JSON in java using the GSON library?

Tags: java, json, gson

In [this link](https://mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/), the author goes through how to use the [GSON library for Java](https://github.com/google/gson). The main example shows how to parse a json file called "staff.json" shown below:

```
{
  "name": "mkyong",
  "age": 35,
  "position": [
    "Founder",
    "CTO",
    "Writer"
  ],
  "skills": [
    "java",
    "python",
    "node",
    "kotlin"
  ],
  "salary": {
    "2018": 14000,
    "2012": 12000,
    "2010": 10000
  }
}
```

The following Java code can read the file, parse it, and create a "Staff" Java object with all the above data loaded, finally printing the java object called "staff" with a lower-case "s":

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class GsonExample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("c:\\projects\\staff.json")) {

            // Convert JSON File to Java Object
            Staff staff = gson.fromJson(reader, Staff.class);
            
            // print staff object
            System.out.println(staff);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Running the above code gives the following output:

> Staff{name='mkyong', age=35, position=[Founder, CTO, Writer],
> skills=[java, python, node, kotlin], salary={2018=14000, 2012=12000,
> 2010=10000}}

Suppose I append the following to "staff.json" so that it looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "mkyong",
  "age": 35,
  "position": [
    "Founder",
    "CTO",
    "Writer"
  ],
  "skills": [
    "java",
    "python",
    "node",
    "kotlin"
  ],
  "salary": {
    "2018": 14000,
    "2012": 12000,
    "2010": 10000
  }
}
\x00\x0d;ldlk4jkladsfl;kmasdlk\d\g\sd===dsafdsfagf\dgas56yjghg\dafd\g\dfa
fdsaffdas]\fg\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\\t\t\t\t\t\t\\\\\s
adfdgt\\\g\\\fdgdf\sg\df<-----END OF FILE HERE NOW
```

As you can see, I'm basically appending a bunch of garbage that is clearly not in Json format.

My question: Assuming you don't know much json-formatted data is in the file (i.e. the skills could have hundreds of items in there), how do I modify the Java code above to extract as much json as possible and disregard the garbage I appended in the new staff.json file? The goal is to get the exact same output shown above from the first staff.json input file.

Comment: What issue are you facing and what problem are you trying to resolve?

Comment: first find valid json string({*}) and then read as java object?

Comment: It doesn’t look like Gson can do what you want.  But [the standard Java EE JSON library](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/bind/package-summary.html) can.

Comment: Jackson also supports this behavior. You can turn it off/on with the `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS`.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to use Gson.  If someone can modify the code above to use jackson that would be great.

Comment: Gson works with "garbage appended" files just fine, since it uses lenient mode for its JsonReader used in the `fromJson` method that means it does not need the whole input stream to be a valid JSON (and should stop after the last `}` token ignoring the whole rest). Did you test it with Gson? And if it fails (I tend to think it doesn't), which version are you using?

Comment: @fluffy, only the `Gson.fromJson(JsonReader, ...)` overloads support trailing "garbage". All other `fromJson` methods try to consume the complete document.